# Creating rule on reverse proxy mod_security

Tags: reverse-proxy, mod-security, mod-security2

I built up the reverse proxy using mod_security on my system

I got problem when wrote rule on specify website

For example i have 2 websites a.com and b.com, both of them has parameter username

if i want to deny value abc on that parameter, my rule will be:

```
SecRule ARGS:username "@streq abc"
```

**but i only want to deny value abc on parameter username at a.com, not b.com**

what should i do?

thank in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1) Only add rule to vhost of a.com

2) Make it a chained rule which also checks this:

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "@streq a.com" "phase:2,id:12345,deny,chain"
   SecRule ARGS:"username" "@streq abc"
```

Comment: thank you, its exactly what im looking for, little modify is ARGS:username not ARGS:"username" :)

Comment: Not sure it matters to be honest. Anyway glad it helped.